# XYZ DaVinci Mini W "jamming" after exactly 5 layers

Tags: xyz-da-vinci-mini-w

I have a DaVinci Mini W that throws a jam error after exactly 5 layers, even if the extruder isn't actually jammed. Is this real jamming, or unethical business practice?

Answer (score 1):

Mini W has both a sensor that checks if there is filament, and a second sensor wheel that checks that the filament is actually moving (so it can deduct available filament length on the NFC tag).

If the moving sensor is not detecting anything for some time, the printing will stop and the LED will go red. I do not know if that will show up as a "jam error" in XYZware or if this is what you experience, but it is my best guess.

I guess the same would happen if you remove the NFC-tag mid-print.